# How to enable and disable an icon on Keypress in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

Below is my input field and I have a class(form--cross) with background image cross(x) in this input form. I want to hide/show the cross icon (Class = "form--cross")based on the Keypress however i have no idea how to do it in angular4.

```html
<div class="form">
  <input [(ngModel)]="templateSearch" type="text" id="search" placeholder="search" class="form--cross" autofocus>
  <button class="btn" (click)="search()"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to disable the input and remove a class when a given key is being pressed?

Comment: @RolandRácz Actually i want to hide this form--cross class(cross icon)  in input when i start writing something it should be enabled and vice-versa

Comment: Please use punctuation marks in your sentences. It is not clear to me what you want. My guess is that you want to remove a class when you have something in your input, and adding it again if it's empty again. Have you tried void's answer? Is this that what you looking for?

Comment: @RolandRácz I have edited my questions, hope you understand it now. Void answer doesnt work.

Comment: When do you want to hide the icon **exactly**? And when do you want to show it **exactly**? Write some examples please in your question, for both cases. It will be easier for us to understand.

Comment: The way to do so is using ngClass appropriately. But is not clear what you want to show/hide; and when. My first understanding is that want to hide the input field on keypressed. Is that right? In that case users won't be able to keep on typing. Please clarfify.

Comment: Okay, I understand it now.

Comment: @RolandRácz I want it all together and below code doesnt work.

Comment: I recommend using `type="search"` then. With the `form--cross` class, you can't do this, because you can't bind an event to clicking on a background cross. If you don't want to use `type="search"`, then you have to figure out a different solution to this problem. You can put an `x` outside of the input for example as a normal HTML tag.

Comment: @RolandRácz I can only use this class form--cross

Comment: Then I can't help you, because it's impossible according to my knowledge. Sorry. Maybe someone else can help you.

Answer (score 1):

In your template (HTML):

```
<div class="form">
    <input #searchInput [(ngModel)]="templateSearch" type="text" id="search" placeholder="search"
        [class.form--cross]="searchInput.value.length == 0" autofocus>
    <button class="btn" (click)="search()"></button>
</div>
```

If you want to hide the cross (hide the class) when the input is losing focus, that is a different kind of question.

If you want to clear the input when you click on the cross, that's a little difficult thing, because you're using CSS for displaying the cross.

If you want to use the exact same cross that you linked in your comment, you can use `type="search"` for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable in .ts and then add / change class using `ngClass` which will take the variable as value and class name as key:

In your **component.ts**

```
showIcon = true;
```

In your **component.html**

```
  <input 
     [(ngModel)]="templateSearch"
     type="text" 
     id="search" 
     placeholder="search" 
     (change)="showIcon=false"
     ngClass="{
       'form--cross': showIcon
     }" 
     autofocus
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to listen to keyup or input event in the input, and bind your ngClass that way [ngClass]="{'form--cross': isWriting}"

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="templateSearch" (input)="onKey($event)" type="text" id="search" placeholder="search" [ngClass]="{'form--cross': isWriting}"  autofocus  >

 onKey(event) {
   this.isWriting = true;
 }
```